# Don't list canned flag options for deleted posts

Tags: feature-request, flags, deleted-posts

[When flagging a deleted post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jv2eJ.png), you can enter a custom message for the moderators, but you also get the canned options: *not an answer* for answers, and *very low quality* for posts with a score < 1.

However, when you actually try to flag a deleted post as such, all that happens is this:

[image: This post has now been deleted. (click on this box to dismiss)]

So why show them in the first place if they won't be accepted anyway? The options for close votes, spam flags and offensive flags are already omitted if the post is deleted.

Comment: This web server doesn't run on your desktop.  Press Ctrl+F5 before voting.

Comment: @UphillLuge Huh?

Comment: Lunboks - I believe @UphillLuge is under the impression that you were flagging a post deleted between your loading and flagging of it. From the screenshot, it is clear that is incorrect, and your browser did know it was deleted.

Comment: @Kevin Oh, I see. Yeah, that's obviously not the case here. If it was, the spam/offensive options wouldn't be absent.

Comment: This feature appears to have been implemented at some point in the past. There's even [a minor bug report from last year](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254594/correct-reference-to-moderator-attention-flag-on-deleted-posts) about the fact that, even though the other options are no longer visible, the description of the custom flag option still refers to a "problem not listed above". This request should be closed and/or marked as [meta-tag:status-completed].