# Correct reference to moderator attention flag on deleted posts

Tags: bug, flags, flag-dialog

When flagging a deleted post for moderator attention, users are prompted with only one option:

> I am flagging to report this answer as...
>
> - **in need of moderator intervention**
>
>   A problem not listed above that requires action by a moderator. *Be specific and detailed!*

Since there is only one option, "[a] problem not listed above" doesn't make sense. Is this something that could be updated; even removing "not listed above" in these instances would suffice in my opinion.

---

This happened while I was reviewing a "First Post" on [TeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com):

[image]

Since posts deleted during the review process aren't updated the same way they are on the main page (for closures and deletions) - with a top-bar display, it's not apparent what's going on when you want to flag something as "not an answer", say.

Comment: It doesn't actually declare there *are* problems listed above. It essentially states "if there's no problem listed above which covers your needs" There being *no* problems listed above "at all" simply means this option is the one to use. I agree your proposal would of course *improve* it (hence my +1), but I'm not convinced it's technically "incorrect".

Comment: Same when flagging a [nomination](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89gNT.png) on election page.