# Flag link for new user own post does nothing

Tags: bug, flags, new-users, unregistered-users

A new user (tested only on an unregistered one) has three links below their own question: share, edit, and flag.

> [image]

The last one (flag) actually doesn't do anything. No popup is appearing. Is there something broken or should that link just be removed?

Comment: They should be able to flag their own post with some limited options. It definitely used to work, or at least I've seen (bad) flags from 1 rep users before. Does the popup not load?

Comment: @Laurel yep, nothing happened on click.

Comment: I think this only occurs for unregistered accounts.

Answer (score 1):

That's interesting. I just clicked flag under a few of my own answers and I saw the following dialog:

[image]

The phrasing "A problem not listed above ..." is wrong, of course, as there are no problems listed above.

Of course, it is difficult to imagine why anybody would want to flag their own answer (or question) but I guess there must be some cases when it has been done.

Flagging your own question gives at least two more options above.

Comment: Did you use your account (*not* a new user, 100+ rep on every site) or a different account that's under 15 reputation?

Comment: @Laurel I used my own account (100+ rep) on both [Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) and [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/). I don't have answers or questions on other accounts. I think this behaviour may be connected to the new user behaviour described in the question

Comment: This is still worth bringing up, but maybe as a separate thread?

Comment: Same happening on **deleted answers**, see [bug-report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/254594/339911). Are your posts deleted?

Comment: " wrong, of course", I dunno, looks _technically correct_ to me - whatever your problem is, it's not listed above!

Comment: @AakashM Yes, I should have been more precise. Better would be: "A problem that requires action by a moderator". "not listed above" is redundant in this particular case.